# Want to bundle Laravel foreach data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a `foreach` loop that i am using to show the dataset, but i want to show specific dataset under a single button so that button click leads to showing that particular data.

My code is the following:

```
@foreach($new_records as $new_recordss)
<tr>
<td scope="col">{{ $new_recordss['Mob'] }}</td>
<td scope="col"><div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs shownum_class"> <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"> </span> show/hide</button><div class="numero_class"><td scope="col">{{ $new_recordss['PreferredDate'] }}</td><td scope="col">{{ $new_recordss['PreferredCity'] }}</td><td scope="col">{{ $new_recordss['BookingId'] }}</td><td scope="col">{{ $new_recordss['Documents'] }}</td><td scope="col">{{ $new_recordss['Age'] }}</td><td scope="col">{{ $new_recordss['Gender'] }}</td></div></div></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Jquery code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".numero_class").hide();
  $(".shownum_class").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".numero_class").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

Currently this is not working.Any pointers will be useful.Plz help

Comment: hmm, wait, so what you did here.. is.. hiding `.numero_class` then add a click event to all `.shownum_class` right? i dont see how the `foreach` is faulty. i do wonder does your `$(document).ready(..)` called after or before jquery declaration - by right it should be after. better to have a `javascript` and `jquery` tag, really. the html for the foreach is showing right? only the js interaction problematic right?

Comment: yes ....what i want is those td elements should show only when there corresponding button is clicked.But current both the <td> and button is showing.And button click is also not working.

Comment: uh, what was my question..? script ordering..? sorry for asking that again, because i cant find that information on your question.. :(

Comment: its ok ....i found an alternative way to pass data to another page on button click.